# Changing The value of struct in an array

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I want to store structs inside an array, access and change the values of the struct in a for loop.

```
struct testing {
    var value:Int
}

var test1 = testing(value: 6 )

test1.value = 2
// this works with no issue

var test2 = testing(value: 12 )

var testings = [ test1, test2 ]

for test in testings{
    test.value = 3
// here I get the error:"Can not assign to 'value' in 'test'"
}
```

If I change the struct to class it works. Can anyone tell me how I can change the value of the struct.

Comment: Also see [value types vs class types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41353620/5175709) Rob correctly says: *if you pass a value type as a parameter to a method that then does something on another thread, you're essentially working with a **copy** of that value type. This ensures the integrity of that object passed to the method.*

Answer (score 129):

Besides what said by @MikeS, remember that structs are value types. So in the `for` loop:

```
for test in testings {
```

a **copy** of an array element is assigned to the `test` variable. Any change you make on it is restricted to the `test` variable, without doing any actual change to the array elements. It works for classes because they are reference types, hence the *reference* and not the *value* is copied to the `test` variable.

The proper way to do that is by using a `for` by index:

```
for index in 0..<testings.count {
    testings[index].value = 15
}
```

in this case you are accessing (and modifying) the actual struct element and not a copy of it.

Comment: Surprisingly this also does not seem to work, and it seems to be changing the value of a copy. See my answer below

Comment: See my comment in your answer - the obtained results are expected because you are still dealing with value types and not reference

Comment: A very subtle difference between two seemingly similar for-loops

Comment: How I don't know that :) Very nice

Comment: Or you can write it like this: `for (index, _) in testings.enumerated() { testings[index].value = 15 }`

Comment: @reza23 - Antonio's answer should be marked as the correct one so that folks looking at this in the future know how to handle it.

Answer (score 14):

To simplify working with value types in arrays you could use following extension (Swift 3):

```
extension Array {
    mutating func modifyForEach(_ body: (_ index: Index, _ element: inout Element) -> ()) {
        for index in indices {
            modifyElement(atIndex: index) { body(index, &$0) }
        }
    }

    mutating func modifyElement(atIndex index: Index, _ modifyElement: (_ element: inout Element) -> ()) {
        var element = self[index]
        modifyElement(&element)
        self[index] = element
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
testings.modifyElement(atIndex: 0) { $0.value = 99 }
testings.modifyForEach { $1.value *= 2 }
testings.modifyForEach { $1.value = $0 }
```

Answer (score 13):

Well I am going to update my answer for swift 3 compatibility.

When you are programming many you need to change some values of objects that are inside a collection. In this example we have an array of struct and given a condition we need to change the value of a specific object. This is a very common thing in any development day.

Instead of using an index to determine which object has to be modified I prefer to use an if condition, which IMHO is more common.

```
import Foundation

struct MyStruct: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var myValue:Int
    var debugDescription: String {
        return "struct is \(myValue)"
    }
}

let struct1 = MyStruct(myValue: 1)
let struct2 = MyStruct(myValue: 2)
let structArray = [struct1, struct2]

let newStructArray = structArray.map({ (myStruct) -> MyStruct in
    // You can check anything like:
    if myStruct.myValue == 1 {
        var modified = myStruct
        modified.myValue = 400
        return modified
    } else {
        return myStruct
    }
})

debugPrint(newStructArray)
```

Notice all the lets, this way of development is safer.

The classes are reference types, it's not needed to make a copy in order to change a value, like it happens with structs. Using the same example with classes:

```
class MyClass: CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    var myValue:Int

    init(myValue: Int){
        self.myValue = myValue
    }

    var debugDescription: String {
        return "class is \(myValue)"
    }
}

let class1 = MyClass(myValue: 1)
let class2 = MyClass(myValue: 2)
let classArray = [class1, class2]

let newClassArray = classArray.map({ (myClass) -> MyClass in
    // You can check anything like:
    if myClass.myValue == 1 {
        myClass.myValue = 400
    }
    return myClass
})

debugPrint(newClassArray)
```

Comment: Isn't doing your "map" purer?

Comment: @IanWarburton Sorry, but I don't understand that, what do you mean by "purer" ?

Comment: I suppose it means more compliant with the functional programming paradigm.

Comment: So, immutability being a functional concept, surely it makes sense to go with a map?

Comment: Well this immutability has to do with how Swift works, in Swift structs are copied and class are passed by reference. So when you are changing a struct or passing it by argument you are making a new copy of it with the value changed. This has nothing to do with functional programming. Check the other answers, they all make copies of the array. Maps do the same thing and you can add conditions and new values while generating the new array. IMHO maps and the others are not exclusively used in functional programming, you can use them whenever you want.

Comment: Passing by value is not the same as immutability. The question is specifically about not being able to mutate a value at all - not that they're changing a value in one place and it's not changing something elsewhere.

Comment: In Swift 3, the 'var' specifier is not allowed. In the map closure, you need to copy the given struct, set the new struct's values, then return the new struct. Tedious.

Answer (score 13):

How to change `Array` of `Structs`

for every element:

```
itemsArray.indices.forEach { itemsArray[$0].someValue = newValue }
```

for specific element:

```
itemsArray.indices.filter { itemsArray[$0].propertyToCompare == true }
                  .forEach { itemsArray[$0].someValue = newValue }
```

Answer (score 5):

You have enough of good answers. I'll just tackle the question from a more generic angle.

As another example to better understand value types and what it means they get copied:

```
struct Item {
    var value:Int

}

func change (item: Item, with value: Int){
    item.value = value //  cannot assign to property: 'item' is a 'let' constant
}
```

That is because item is **copied**, when it comes in, it is immutable — as a convenience.

Had you made `Item` a class type then you were able to change its value.

---

```
var item2 = item1 // mutable COPY created
item2.value = 10
print(item2.value) // 10
print(item1.value) // 5
```

Answer (score 2):

This is very tricky answer. I think, **You should not do like this**:

```
struct testing {
    var value:Int
}

var test1 = testing(value: 6)
var test2 = testing(value: 12)

var ary = [UnsafeMutablePointer<testing>].convertFromArrayLiteral(&test1, &test2)

for p in ary {
    p.memory.value = 3
}

if test1.value == test2.value {
    println("value: \(test1.value)")
}
```

For Xcode 6.1, array initialization will be

```
var ary = [UnsafeMutablePointer<testing>](arrayLiteral: &test1, &test2)
```

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use the map function to get this effect - essentially creating a new array

```
itemsArray = itemsArray.map { 
  var card = $0
  card.isDefault = aCard.token == token
  return card
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up recreating a new array of struct see the example below.

```
func updateDefaultCreditCard(token: String) {
    var updatedArray: [CreditCard] = []
    for aCard in self.creditcards {
        var card = aCard
        card.isDefault = aCard.token == token
        updatedArray.append(card)
    }
    self.creditcards = updatedArray
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I tried Antonio's answer which seemed quite logical but to my surprise it does not work. Exploring this further I tried the following:

```
struct testing {
    var value:Int
}

var test1 = testing(value: 6 )
var test2 = testing(value: 12 )

var testings = [ test1, test2 ]

var test1b = testings[0]
test1b.value = 13

// I would assume this is same as test1, but it is not test1.value is still 6

// even trying 

testings[0].value = 23

// still the value of test1 did not change.
// so I think the only way is to change the whole of test1

test1 = test1b
```

Comment: You are forgetting that every time you pass a value type around, you pass a copy of it, not a reference. So the results you have are expected. `testing` is initialized with a **copy** of `test1` and `test2`. Again, in `var test1b = testings[0]` you are creating a new copy of `testings[0]`, which is itself a copy of `test1`