# If arrays are value types and therefore get copied, then how are they not thread safe?

Tags: arrays, swift, multithreading, struct, value-type

Reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38903479/5175709) I learn that:

> Instances of value types are not shared: every thread gets its own copy.* That means that every thread can read and write to its instance without having to worry about what other threads are doing.

Then I was brought to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28784770/5175709) answer and its comment

and was told:

> an array, which is not, itself, thread-safe, is being accessed from
>   multiple threads, so all interactions must be synchronized.

& about *every thread gets its own copy* I was told

> if one thread is updating an array (presumably so you can see that
>   edit from another queue), that simply doesn't apply

**that simply doesn't apply**  <-- Why not?

I initially thought all of this is happening because the array ie a value type is getting wrapped into a class but to my amazement I was told NOT true! So I'm back to Swift 101 again :D

Comment: I highly suggest to read this other answer as well [Thread safety of value types](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41353620/5175709)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The fundamental issue is the interpretation of "every thread gets its own copy".

Yes, we often use value types to ensure thread safety by providing every thread its own copy of an object (such as an array). But that is not the same thing as claiming that value types guarantee every thread will get its own copy.

Specifically, using closures, multiple threads can attempt to mutate the same value-type object. Here is an example of code that shows some non-thread-safe code interacting with a Swift `Array` value type:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global()

var employees = ["Bill", "Bob", "Joe"]

queue.async {
    let count = employees.count
    for index in 0 ..< count {
        print("\(employees[index])")
        Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
    }
}

queue.async { 
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
    employees.remove(at: 0)
}
```

(You generally wouldn't add `sleep` calls; I only added them to manifest race conditions that are otherwise hard to reproduce. You also shouldn't mutate an object from multiple threads like this without some synchronization, but I'm doing this to illustrate the problem.)

In these `async` calls, you're still referring to the same `employees` array defined earlier. So, in this particular example, we'll see it output "Bill", it will skip "Bob" (even though it was "Bill" that was removed), it will output "Joe" (now the second item), and then it will crash trying to access the third item in an array that now only has two items left.

Now, all that I illustrate above is that a single value type *can* be mutated by one thread while being used by another, thereby violating thread-safety. There are actually a whole series of more fundamental problems that can manifest themselves when writing code that is not thread-safe, but the above is merely one slightly contrived example.

But, you can ensure that this separate thread gets its own copy of the `employees` array by adding a "capture list" to that first `async` call to indicate that you want to work with a copy of the original `employees` array:

```
queue.async { [employees] in
    ...
}
```

Or, you'll automatically get this behavior if you pass this value type as a parameter to another method:

```
doSomethingAsynchronous(with: employees) { result in
    ...
}
```

In either of these two cases, you'll be enjoying value semantics and see a copy (or copy-on-write) of the original array, although the original array may have been mutated elsewhere.

Bottom line, my point is merely that value types do not *guarantee* that every thread has its own copy. The `Array` type is not (nor are many other mutable value types) thread-safe. But, like all value types, Swift offer simple mechanisms (some of them completely automatic and transparent) that will provide each thread its own copy, making it much easier to write thread-safe code.

---

Here's another example with another value type that makes the problem more obvious. Here's an example where a failure to write thread-safe code returns semantically invalid object:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue.global()

struct Person {
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
}

var person = Person(firstName: "Rob", lastName: "Ryan")

queue.async {
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
    print("1: \(person)")
}

queue.async { 
    person.firstName = "Rachel"
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 1)
    person.lastName = "Moore"
    print("2: \(person)")
}
```

In this example, the first print statement will say, effectively "Rachel Ryan", which is neither "Rob Ryan" nor "Rachel Moore". In short, we're examining our `Person` while it is in an internally inconsistent state.

But, again, we can use a capture list to enjoy value semantics:

```
queue.async { [person] in
    Thread.sleep(forTimeInterval: 0.5)
    print("1: \(person)")
}
```

And in this case, it will say "Rob Ryan", oblivious to the fact that the original `Person` may be in the process of being mutated by another thread. (Clearly, the real problem is not fixed just by using value semantics in the first `async` call, but synchronizing the second `async` call and/or using value semantics there, too.)

Comment: hmmm. So in a very gross simplification, ownership of something can become problematic either by being a reference type (or wrapped into one) or multi-threading. Here you demonstrated it with multi-threading... or If copied or captured then things would be differently...

Comment: I might rephrase that because the issue here only really manifests itself when dealing with multi-threaded code: "When writing multi-threaded code, you either should synchronize access to the object in question, or, where using value types, employ value semantics to ensure local copies of objects in one thread cannot simultaneously be mutated by another thread."

Comment: @Rob , "There are actually a whole series of more fundamental problems that can manifest themselves when writing code that is not thread-safe" – just trying to absorb more knowledge, could you please elaborate and put just a list of problems so that we could dive a bit deeper ourselves? It'd be much more valuable since it would speak from experience. Would be a bit unrelated but very much appreciated, thanks for your replies!

Comment: @Ian - In the above example, it was in an internally inconsistent state, but no damage is done. In other cases, e.g. unsynchronized appending to an array, you can experience data loss (where items are just missing) or, worse, crashes such as “EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=EXC_I386_GPFLT)”. I might suggest that you check out the Thread Sanitizer (TSAN), which will help you identify all sorts of different problems. [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/code_diagnostics/thread_sanitizer/enabling_the_thread_sanitizer) lists the types of thread-safety issues it identifies.

Comment: Apple has broken the above link. But see https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_memory_thread_and_crash_issues_early/

Answer (score 2):

Because `Array` is a value type, you're guaranteed that it has a single **direct** owner.

The issue comes from what happens when an array has more than one **indirect** owner. Consider this example:

```
Class Foo {
    let array = [Int]()

    func fillIfArrayIsEmpty() {
        guard array.isEmpty else { return }
        array += [Int](1...10)
    }
}

let foo = Foo();

doSomethingOnThread1 {
    foo.fillIfArrayIsEmpty()
}

doSomethingOnThread2 {
    foo.fillIfArrayIsEmpty()
}
```

`array` has a single direct owner: the `foo` instance it's contained in. However, both thread 1 and 2 have ownership of `foo`, and transitively, of the `array` within it. This means they can both mutate it asynchronously, so race conditions can occur.

Here's an example of what might occur:

- Thread 1 starts running
- `array.isEmpty` evaluates to false, the guard passes, and execution will continue passed it
- Thread 1 has used up its CPU time, so it's kicked off the CPU. Thread 2 is scheduled on by the OS
- Thread 2 is now running
- `array.isEmpty` evaluates to false, the guard passes, and execution will continue passed it
- `array += [Int](1...10)` is executed. `array` is now equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`
- Thread 2 is finished, and relinquishes the CPU, Thread 1 is scheduled on by the OS
- Thread 1 resumes where it left off.
- `array += [Int](1...10)` is executed. `array` is now equal to `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]`. This wasn't supposed to happen!

Comment: when you say race condition can occur you mean as if the moment thread1 tried to add, the last written index was 5 so it attempts to write at index6, but all of a sudden other threads have wrote at indexed 6,7,8 which makes it problematic?

Comment: @Honey I'll give an example in my answer in a sec, but race conditions are really well explained by other resources, so I don't want to spend a lot of time going into detail.

Comment: *its CPU time, so it's kicked off* you mean as in context switching, so the CPU shifts to thread2, then shifts back to Thread1, then again to thread2 and the result is something as scrambled as `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]` or possibly more scrambled than that. || Thank you so much for this answer Alex. If I could mark 2 answer I would have.

Comment: Yep, a context switch. You can mark the better of the two answers ;)

Comment: but the end result could have been anything more scrambled right?

Comment: It would be an ascending list with either 1 of each of the digits, or 2 of each of the digits

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131629/discussion-between-honey-and-alexander).

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong assumption. You think that whatever you do with structs a copy will always magically happen. NOT true. If you copy them they will be copied as simple as that.

```
class someClass{ 
var anArray : Array = [1,2,3,4,5]

func copy{
var copiedArray = anArray // manipulating copiedArray & anArray at the same time will NEVER create a problem
} 

func myRead(_ index : Int){
print(anArray[index])
}

func myWrite(_ item : Int){
anArray.append(item)
}
}
```

However inside your read & write funcs you are accessing `anArray`—**without copying** it, so race-conditions *can* occur if both myRead and myWrite functions are called concurrently. You have to solve (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28784507/adding-items-to-swift-array-across-multiple-threads-causing-issues-because-arra?noredirect=1&lq=1)) the issue by using queues.