# How to call a function with an `inout` argument on each element of array?

Tags: swift, swift3

I have a function which takes `inout` argument

```
 func modify(word: inout Word)
```

I need to call it on each element of array. Here is what I do

```
for word in words {
    modify(word: &word)
}
```

But I get error:

> cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: 'word' is a 'let' constant

I tried to iterate through `map` `words.map{ modify(word:&$0) }`, still the same error:

> cannot pass immutable value as inout argument: '0$' is immutable

Is there any way to call a function with an `inout` argument on each element of array?

Comment: Don't use inout.  If you must then you will need to iterate over the array, building a new array with the modified words or use an index variable rather than enumeration

Comment: Closely related: [Changing The value of struct in an array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371751/changing-the-value-of-struct-in-an-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `for word in words` syntax, `word` is actually an immutable copy of the element in the array.

To modify the array directly, iterate over the indices instead:

```
for i in words.indices {
    modify(word: &words[i])
}
```

which is equivalent to (for arrays at least)

```
for i in 0..<words.count {
    modify(word: &words[i])
}
```

Comment: Deleting my answer after seeing your's. I never knew this and posted a less "Swifty" version of your answer! Nice!

Comment: Note that `words` still needs to be declared with `var`, not `let`.