# How to change a value of struct that is in array?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct

I'm using swift for my project.

I have an array of structs named `Instrument`. Later on I made a function that returns specific `Instrument` from array. Then I wanted to change value on one of its property, but this change is not reflected inside the array.

I need to have this array to include all the changes on the elements inside. What do you think is the best practice here?

- Change `Instrument` from `struct` to `class`.
- Somehow rewrite the function that returns `Instrument` from array.

Right now I use this function:

```
func instrument(for identifier: String) -> Instrument? {
  if let instrument = instruments.filter({ $0.identifier == identifier }).first {
    return instrument
  }
  return nil
}
```

I start with the struct because swift is known to be language for structs and I want to learn when to use `struct` of `class`.

thanks

Comment: Note that you could use `first(where:)` rather than `filter(_:)` and `first`.

Comment: Structs are value type. After changing the property you have to assign the item back to the array. But don't fight the framework! If you need reference type, use a class.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26375105/312312

Comment: Is an Array an appropriate choice in this case? Seems like a Dictionary mapping `identifier`s to `Instrument`s would be a good choice

Comment: Ok, looks like I need to switch to dictionary and also use reference type. Thanks

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With an array of struct Instrument, you can obtain the index for the Instrument with a particular identifier, and use that to access and modify a property of the Instrument.

```
struct Instrument {
    let identifier: String
    var value: Int
}

var instruments = [
    Instrument(identifier: "alpha", value: 3),
    Instrument(identifier: "beta", value: 9),
]

if let index = instruments.index(where: { $0.identifier == "alpha" }) {
    instruments[index].value *= 2
}

print(instruments) // [Instrument(identifier: "alpha", value: 6), Instrument(identifier: "beta", value: 9)]
```

Comment: `instruments.index` is now `instruments.firstIndex`

Comment: this is the best answer, its all about the value type

Answer (score 3):

If you stick to the value type approach (and given that the `identifier` is not unique: otherwise, consider using a dictionary for simple extract-and-replace logic), you could write a mutating function to the type which owns the `[Instruments]` array, which finds a (first) `Instrument` instance in the array and mutates it using a supplied closure. E.g. (thanks @Hamish for improvements!):

```
struct Instrument {
    let identifier: String
    var changeThis: Int
    init(_ identifier: String, _ changeThis: Int) {
        self.identifier = identifier
        self.changeThis = changeThis
    }
}

struct Foo {
    var instruments: [Instrument]

    @discardableResult // do not necessarily make use of the return result (no warning if not)
    mutating func updateInstrument(forFirst identifier: String,
            using mutate: (inout Instrument) -> ()) -> Bool {
        if let idx = instruments.indices
            .first(where: { instruments[$0].identifier == identifier }) {

            // mutate this instrument (in-place) using supplied closure
            mutate(&instruments[idx])

            return true // replacement successful
        }
        return false // didn't find such an instrument
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```
var foo = Foo(instruments:
    [Instrument("a", 1), Instrument("b", 2),
     Instrument("c", 3), Instrument("b", 4)])

// make use of result of call
if foo.updateInstrument(forFirst: "b", using: { $0.changeThis = 42 }) {
    print("Successfully mutated an instrument")
} // Successfully mutated an instrument

// just attempt mutate and discard the result
foo.updateInstrument(forFirst: "c", using: { $0.changeThis = 99 })

print(foo.instruments)
/* [Instrument(identifier: "a", changeThis: 1), 
    Instrument(identifier: "b", changeThis: 42), 
    Instrument(identifier: "c", changeThis: 99),
    Instrument(identifier: "b", changeThis: 4)] */
```

---

As shown in [@Owen:s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41666203/4573247), an even neater approach to finding the first index for a certain predicate on the element is using the [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1688966-index) method of array (rather than `indices.first(where:)` as used above). Using the `index(where:)` approach in the complete example above would simply correspond to replacing

```
if let idx = instruments.indices
    .first(where: { instruments[$0].identifier == identifier }) { ...
```

with

```
if let idx = instruments
    .index(where: { $0.identifier == identifier }) { ...
```

in the `updateInstrument(forFirst:using)` method of `Foo`.

We could further condense the `updateInstrument(forFirst:using)` method by applying the `map` function of `Optional` to perform the (possible) replacement and boolean return in a single line:

```
struct Foo {
    var instruments: [Instrument]

    @discardableResult
    mutating func updateInstrument(forFirst identifier: String,
        using mutate: (inout Instrument) -> ()) -> Bool {
        return instruments
            .index(where: { $0.identifier == identifier })
            .map { mutate(&instruments[$0]) } != nil
    }
}
```