# Swift closure to iterate over a class object

Tags: swift

Curious to know if anyone has a swift closure solution to transform the following for/in loop iteration over an array containing multiple class objects?  The class is composed of two properties of type string.  A class function instantiates multiple objects and places them into an array.  In the example below, the array nhSearchObject has 10 indices containing 10 objects of the class.

```
class President{
   var firstName:String 
   var lastName:String
    init(...)
    }       
  // class function creates objects and places them into an array   nhSearchObject

for i in nhSearchObject[0...6] {
    i.firstName = "George"
    i.lastName = "Washington"
}
```

It is imperative to preserve the subscript range feature as I only want to change the indices 0...6.  Also, I do not want to create a new array.  Simply interested in iterating over the array slice 0..6 of the 10 indices of the existing array to modify object properties.

Comment: What's wrong with the `for in` loop? It's both clear and concise.

Comment: *has 10 elements containing 11 objects of the class.* how's that possible?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with it.  I am learning closures and can't figure out how to use a closure to iterate over an array using an array slice.

Comment: @Honey the first element is 0 so there are 11 objects in the array

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you. e.g. `let arr = [1,5,4]`. <-- has 3 indexes and 3 values inside. arr[0] is 1, arr[1] is 5, arr[2] is 4

Comment: @Honey I'm not sure if it really matters how one might count the objects for purposes of answering the question.  However, yes, I see your point.  3 indices has three objects inside.  For the sake of clarity I edited the text.

Comment: `nhSearchObject[0...6].forEach { ... }` or `nhSearchObject.prefix(7).forEach { ... }` ?

Comment: @MartinR. Thx.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: @MartinR This is embarrassing. I'm following the same logic, but can't get it to work. `var x = [1,2,3];
var m = x[0...2].forEach{$0*5};print(x)// [1,2,3];print(m) // ()`. `m` only prints to`()`.

Comment: @Honey: You are confusing two things. A class is a *reference type,* therefore you can modify the properties of the (referenced) array elements in `nhSearchObject[0...6].forEach { $0.firstName = "George" }`. An array is a struct and a *value type,* where you cannot do that. Also `forEach` does not *return* anything. `let m = x[0...2].map { $0 * 5 }` would create a new array, but that is different from what you originally asked.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks (I'm not the OP). I *somewhat* see what you are saying. *An array is a struct and a value type, where you cannot do that*. so how come I do `x.sort()` and it sorts ie modifying itself.

Comment: @Honey: sort() rearranges the array elements, it does not modify the properties of its elements. What I meant is: In your example `x[0...2].forEach{$0*5}` the `$0` is a *value* and a "copy" of an element in `x`. In `nhSearchObject[0...6].forEach { $0.firstName = "George" }` the `$0` is a *reference* to an object.

Comment: @MartinR - it worked!  Thx.

Comment: @honey, the answer of your question lies [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26371751/changing-the-value-of-struct-in-an-array)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all your class is `President` (no `Presidents`)

```
class President {
    var firstName:String
    var lastName:String
    init(firstName: String, lastName:String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

Now given the following array

```
let presidents: [President] = ...
```

you can follow 2 approaches

### If you are sure the array has at least 7 elements then

```
presidents[0...6].forEach { president in
    president.firstName = "George"
    president.lastName = "Washington"
}
```

### Otherwise

```
presidents
    .enumerated()
    .filter { $0.offset <= 6 }
    .forEach { elm in
        elm.element.firstName = "George"
        elm.element.lastName = "Washington"
    }
```

Comment: At first I thought to myself: I can name a class whatever I want.  However, I agree that the proper name for the class would be President in the singular given that one creates multiple objects of the class.  Thank you for the correction.

Comment: I think you meant `$0.offset < 6`, however, you probably want to use `prefix(6)` instead of `enumerated` and `filter`.

Comment: AppzYourLife - Thank you for the code solutions. I believe that your code, consistent with that of @MartinR's solution noted in the above comments, are correct.

Answer (score -1):

nhSearchObject.forEach { $0.firstName = "George"; $0.lastName = "Washington" }

Comment: How does the closure apply to elements 0...6 of 10 array elements?  the solution proposed would apply to all 10 elements of the nhSearchObject.