# How to reassign a variable's value inside a struct?

Tags: swift, struct

I have a struct "`Person`" which I want to reassign each individual object's `amount` from the `structArray` which I declared. When I do a for each loop to reassign the `amount`, an error says

> Left side of mutating operator isn't mutable: 'person' is a 'let' constant

```
struct Person {

    let name : String
    var amount : Double
}

var structArray:[Person] = []

func calculateBill(pax: [Person]) -> [Person] {

    for person in pax {

        person.amount += taxByPerson //error
    }

    return pax
}
```

What is causing the issue and how can I fix this to be able to reassign the value?

EDIT: Thanks guys for pointing out where my error was, although the downvoting is pretty depressing to watch lol.

```
func calculateBill(pax: [Person]) -> [Person] {

    var finalBill:[Person] = pax        

    for i in 0..<finalBill.count {

        finalBill[i].amount += taxByPerson      
    }

    return finalBill
}
```

Comment: The function does not compile anyway

Comment: Why not? @vadian

Comment: The parameter label `newPax` is not related to the function

Comment: Oh, sorry. Syntax problem. Edited

Comment: You need to 1) create a mutable copy of the array inside the function and 2) create a mutable copy of the person inside the for loop and then assign it back to the array after mutating it.

Comment: @iamhx Does it make sense for a person's name to be mutable? 0.o

Comment: @Alexander You're right. Since theres no need to reassign the name

Comment: Note that your updated code won't mutate the actual elements in the array because `person` in the loop is a mutable *copy* of the given array element at that iteration. One way to do what you want is to iterate over indices instead, see for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/26371751/2976878

Answer (score 0):

Well the error is exactly what it says on the tin... `person` is a let context. You'll need to use `var`. But this is more easily accomplished with `map`

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var amount: Double
}

var people = [Person]()

func calculateBill(_ people: [Person]) -> [Person] {
    return people.map{ 
        var p = $0
        p.amount += taxByPerson
        return p
    }
}
```

Comment: That won't work because `$0` is immutable and `+=` returns `Void`. `return people.map { Person(name: $0.name, amount: $0.amount + taxByPerson) }` perhaps? :)

Comment: @Hamish Fixed, although it does ruin some of the charm

Answer (score 0):

Value types could be a pain and passed parameters are constants (`let`) by definition.

You could pass the array as an `inout` parameter, in the function add the value directly in the array:

```
func calculateBill(pax: inout [Person]) {
    for index in 0..<pax.count {
        pax[index].amount += taxByPerson
    }
}
```

and call it

```
calculateBill(pax: &structArray)
```

Comment: Or `for index in pax.indices {...}` – also you can totally get rid of the `var people = pax` & `pax = people` given you're just mutating `pax` anyway.